# Android NDK includes

Tags: android, android-ndk, include, java-native-interface

Suppose my Android project uses jni with next structure:

```
jni__
     |__src__
             |__first.c
             |__second.c
             |
             |__include__
                         |__first.h
```

There are two source files in src directory and one header file in src/include director.

***first.h:***

```
#include <string.h>

#ifndef FIRST_H
#define FIRST_H

extern char * text();

#endif
```

***first.c:***

```
#include "first.h"

char * text() {
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

***second.c:***

```
#include "first.h"
#include <jni.h>

jbyteArray Java_com_example_android_MainActivity_getText( JNIEnv*  env, jobject this) {
    char * str = text();
    ...
    return str;
}
```

How to compile this source and correctly specify the directory with headers in Android.mk file?

Now my ***Android.mk*** file is as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_SRC_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../src

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../src/include

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_SRC_PATH)/first.c \
                    $(LOCAL_SRC_PATH)/second.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But when I try to build this sources compilation terminated with error: *"first.h: No such file or directory"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/include` should do it. As stated in ANDROID-MK file in NDK docs that you can find in your NDK directory, $(LOCAL_PATH) refers to the directory that your Android.mk file is located. Assuming that it is located in jni directory, $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/include points to your header directory where the missing file is located.

And I would use `#include <first.h>` rather than using `#include "first.h"` according to the general convention of using headers.

Comment: Unfortunatelly $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/include also doesn't work.  I don't sure where $(LOCAL_PATH) is refers but LOCAL_SRC_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../src refers to the jni/src directory.

Comment: Add LOCAL_C_INCLUDES inside your module. I mean, after include $(CLEAR_VARS) and before include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)